# Is it possible to convert a open inventor scenegraph into a threejs scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js, openscenegraph

I want to visualize open inventor scengraph in webgl form! How can I approach this work? any ideas!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Coin to import to OpenSceneGraph, then use osgjs to export to a format three can read.